# Asp.net "An error occurred while uploading. Please verify you are uploading an allowed file extension and try again."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29ByA.png)

I have tried using the FileUpload control in ASP.net {/general/CustomFieldFileUpload.aspx} and found some strange problems IN THE PIC .
but when I have tried using the FileUpload control in ASP.net {/general/CustomFieldFileUpload.aspx?controlID=cdlCustomFieldValueIDPRCardUpload} it's download normally.

I want know if there other link to upload files  directly without admin permision?? like those links
1: /general/CustomFieldFileUpload.aspx
2:/general/CustomFieldFileUpload.aspx?controlID=cdlCustomFieldValueIDPRCardUpload

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `I want know if there other link to upload files directly without admin permision?`I'm afraid not,without permission,you cannot upload files to somewhere which needs permission.